# Pass image from PHP to as3/air mobile app

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I have a need to pass an image from a server to a AS3/Air app built for iOS and Android however I don't know the best method of storing the image data in the app.

I have an app that allows users to register using Facebook connect. If they choose to use Facebook I grab their profile image and store it on my server using:

```
$img = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid. '/picture?width=190&height=190');
$file = $dir . '/' . $fbid. '.jpg';
file_put_contents($file, $img);
```

This works great and I can see the profile image being saved. I would then like to send this image to the app once the user logs into their account each time (during the sign in validation process). The pics are small in file size (about 10kb).

Would the best method be save the image locally and call from local storage, or load the image from the URL and then cache...

Cheers!

Comment: Well, if you are taking the image from fb, why waste resources and save it on your server? It's better to just show it from URL, that way you'll always have user's latest image.

Comment: I was only thinking of storing it on my servers because the user may not always authenticate with Facebook. Users are required to create an account in my app so the information from Facebook was to only prefill the form data and grab their profile image.